# Move home directories for users who don't exist?

Tags: linux, users, mv, home

Some time ago we migrated services from an old CentOs installation to RedHat. Part of this process was copying the `/home` directory to the new installation.

The new RedHat installation has fewer users than that old CentOs installation. We would like to move any directory in the `/home` directory that does not have a user to `/home/abandoned`.

How can this be done?

I would like to do it in one operation. The `/home/abandoned` directory is only temporary. We will eventually delete that directory once we are sure all the non-user directories are not needed

This will be a one time process, so it doesn't have to be flexible or pretty.

*edit*

I believe that the following will work, but I don't want to run it without some input from the folks here. Does this look acceptable? `find /home -maxdepth 1 -nouser -type d -exec mv {} /home/abandoned/. \;`

*/edit*

Comment: Bad choice of location. Under `/home` there should be users' folders only. Other than that I don't understand your question. What is stopping you from moving those folders to anywhere else you consider fit?

Comment: I believe that the following will work, but I don't want to run it without some input from the folks here. Does this look acceptable?

find /home -maxdepth 1 -nouser -type d -exec mv {} /home/abandoned/. \;

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia - I would like to do it in one operation.  The /home/abandoned directory is only temporary. We will eventually delete that directory once we are sure all the non-user directories are not needed.

Comment: Your comment should be a part of the question. It shows your research effort, something we like. Please [edit] the question.

Answer (score 0):

**Please don't forget to cd to home, you definitely don't want to run the last command from /.**

To list all the directories with no user:

```
cd /home ; find -type d -maxdepth 1 -nouser
```

**DANGEROUS** To move them AFTER checking them:

```
cd /home ; mkdir abandoned; find -type d -maxdepth 1 -nouser -exec mv -iv \{\} 'abandoned' \;
```

Comment: Little less dangerous: `cd /home && mkdir abandoned && find …`.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, users' /home directories are named after the username of the user.  As a simple preliminary check, you can check the directory name in /home against the username in /etc/passwd.  If you find no matching record in /etc/passwd, then you can further validate your decision process with the -nouser argument to the find command.